# Angular 2: How to create a common Create and Edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a **buildEditComponent** that a user navigates to on button click. In this component, I check with the route params, if there's an **id** or **add** and thus decide whether to show a **create** or **edit** form.

```
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        this.userId = params['id'];
  if(this.userId !== 'add')
    this.userEditable = true;
    });
```

Now inside my **html**, I have 2 **divs**, one for **create** and the other for **edit**.

```
//Edit form
<div *ngIf="userEditable" class="formfield spaceBottom25 [formGroup]="menuForm">...</div>

//Create form
<div *ngIf="!userEditable">...</div>
```

This approach creates two divs with almost similar fields. i want to use the same form for both the **create** and **edit** operations, but using **formGroup** with **ngModel** is creating issues. Can anybody suggest some blogs or approaches to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use 1 template and 1 model? If the id is available, just load the data to the model otherwise create a blank model.

Comment: I have a single template. Just that I'm using the two divs and show/hide them based on whether there's and edit or create request.

Comment: My point is you don't even need to show/hide them. You only have 1 template/form and bind to 1 model. The only difference between 2 scenarios is 1 has model with loaded data and 1 doesn't.

Comment: If you could explain this further with a demonstration that would be extremely helpful. I am trying to decide the best practice on a user creation page. I want to be able to click create and edit the created user on the same page. Or is best practice to create a /edit and /create.